# PonyORM: Mapping is not generated for entity ‘User’

Tags: python, flask, ponyorm

I’m trying to learn and build small app with PonyOrm and Flask. For that I’ve copied example app from [Pony’s GitHub](https://github.com/ponyorm/pony/tree/orm/pony/flask/example). But I still get the same error:

```
pony.orm.core.ERDiagramError: Mapping is not generated for entity 'User'
```

I’ve been looking for answers on Google and in Pony documentation, to no avail.

Comment: It would be better to raise that issue on their Github issues directly than asking here.

Answer (score 1):

Add this line after the creation of the entity and before you tries to map:

```
db.generate_mapping(create_tables=True) # create tables
```

Worked for me.